# Using AngularJS and Firebase to make a master detail view

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, master-detail

I made a site using AngularJS / bootstrap. It gives a list of items using a firebase array.

I want to be able to click on the returned results and have some details displayed.

At present I am using one controller only. Id like to keep it this way if possible because I am totally new to this.

Controller.js Code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

myApp.controller('ResultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope,$firebaseArray) {

var myResults = new Firebase('https://my-firebaseURL.firebaseio.com/results').orderByChild('NewRoomName');

$scope.results = $firebaseArray(myResults);


}]);
```

My Index.html uses ng repeat and gives me 3 items from the array only. I would like to click on the row that contains the item and have the remaining details displayed.

Relevant Index.html Code

```
    <div class="panel panel-body">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Room</td>
            <td>Old Name</td>
            <td>Location</td>


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="results in results">
            <td>{{ results.NewRoomName}}</td>
            <td>{{ results.OldRoomName }}</td>
            <td>{{ results.Floor }}</td>


        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I assumed that I would use ng-click and ng-show but I have tried and i think I am missing a fundamental step somewhere along the way.

I've also googled the shiznit out of this but can't quite find what I need. I found a half decent you tube video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Er8w4ROm8E4) but i still can't seem to get it working.

I have seen mentioned 'factories'. I was really hoping to avoid that on this particular pet project but if it can't be helped then I will have to suck it up I guess.

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Full working demo so far is here http://goo.gl/rr4jgP

Answer (score 0):

*One note is to call repeat **result** in results instead of reuslts in results*

This would depend on how you have your data structured in Fireabse but generally you would like to have an ngClick that takes the result into the function and then does something with that data like populates it in a modal or something.

Alternatively if the data is structured in such a way that every object has sub-objects for example result.newRoom has an attribute result.newRoom.number then you can have an accordion that displays that detail on click.

Look at documentation for bootstrap accordions:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Within the accordion content you could have something like:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  {{result.newRoomName.number}}
</div>
```

If you want to use ngClick it would look like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="displayDetails(result)">
  <td>{{ results.NewRoomName}}</td>
  <td>{{ results.OldRoomName }}</td>
  <td>{{ results.Floor }}</td>
</tr>
```

Then your js would be:

```
$scope.displayResults = function(result){
  //Display Results
  $scope.selectedResult = result
}
```

The $scope.selectedResult could be bound to something in the template that displays the details result

Comment: thank you for this I will try. The data is structured so that each room has attributes fwiw so Room ID, Floor, Name etc. Very simple JSON structure. Where would the JS go, part of the existing controller or in a new one?

Comment: hi, just wanted to say I worked with your solution and it worked out just perfectly. Sorry for the delay